# pure JS how to have multiple mouseleave event listeners

Tags: javascript, event-listener, mouseleave

Trying to listen to 2 mouse events each on different elements.  Here's the JS

```
function moveDown(event) {
  const submenus = document.getElementsByClassName('sub-menu')
  var navbar = document.getElementById("menu-1");

  var sub

  if (event.target.innerHTML === "ABOUT US") {
    sub = submenus[0]
  } else {
    sub = submenus[1]
  }

  var rect = sub.getBoundingClientRect();
  navbar.style.marginBottom = rect.height + "px"
}


function moveUp(event) {
  var navbar = document.getElementById("menu-1");
  navbar.style.marginBottom = 0
}

(function() {
  var takeAction = document.getElementsByClassName('takeAction')[0]
  var aboutUs = document.getElementsByClassName('aboutUs')[0]

  aboutUs.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
    moveDown(event)
  }, {
    passive: false
  })
  takeAction.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
    moveDown(event)
  }, {
    passive: false
  })

  aboutUs.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(event) {
    moveUp(event)
  }, {
    passive: false
  })
  takeAction.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(event) {
    moveUp(event)
  }, {
    passive: false
  })
})()
```

This works on the second element "takeAction" but the mouseleave listener on the first element "aboutUs" seems to work as mouseout

UPDATE:

I tried to produce a working snippet of the problem but this is done in wordpress and I'm unable to do so.  However, here's a link to the [site](https://www.sustainablewestonma.org)

If you hover over "ABOUT US" and then hover over "TAKE ACTION" you'll see the problem

Comment: Can you add the HTML? The difference between `mouseleave` and `mouseout` depends on how elements are nested.

Comment: It would best if you posted a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: `aboutUs.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {moveDown(event)}` destroys the value of *this* in the listener (it's set to window or undefined). Consider `aboutUs.addEventListener('mouseover', moveDown)` then in *moveDown* *this* will refer to the related element (event.target).

Comment: @RobG your answer is correct but it really confuses me.  I thought I had two different listeners each looking for the mouseover event.  Why is one listener interferring with the other? Also, if I'm passing function(event) to moveDown(event)   (ok, not very efficient) why is that different from just calling moveDown(event) directly as you suggest?

Comment: It's not an answer, it's a comment about how you're setting the listener. BTW, I don't see any difference in behaviour between the two menu items. Until you can post a minimal example here, you likely won't get an answer.